# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am working on a Cryptocurrency tracker using React.JS and API. In my App.js I am having an error while running it on localhost.

**App.js**

code:-

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';  
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';

function App() {
 const [coins, setCoins] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      axios
      .get(
         'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false'
      )
    .then(res => {
     setCoins(res.data)
    //  console.log(res.data);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
  },  []);
```

**index.js**

code:-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

***Error*** :-
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Comment: Not a difficult topic to search for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%2bcors?tab=Frequent or on any search engine. There are many thousands of similar questions all over the web

Comment: your API server should enable the cross origin requests. For more info. https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Just have { crossDomain: true } , sent along with axios request  `axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false' , { crossDomain: true } )` .................

Answer (score 0):

To avoid cors issues in your **dev environment**  you can use a proxy provided by e.g. `http-proxy-middleware` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)

With it installed you can create a file named setupProxy.js in your `/src` directory like:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use(
    '/coingecko',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '/coingecko': '/',
      },
    })
  );
};
```

In your axios request, you will be able to use:

```
useEffect(() => {
      axios
      .get(
         '/coingecko/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false'
      )
    .then(res => {
     setCoins(res.data)
    //  console.log(res.data);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
  },  []);
```